# UIImage Fade in after load on my UITable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, fadein

I have an UIImage that loads from the web, and I'd like it to fade in when it displays in my UITableCell.

```
if([thumb image])
{
    UIImage *imagen = [thumb.image retain];
    [imagen drawInRect:CGRectMake(15, 4, 44, 44)];
    [imagen release];
}
```

How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animate the alpha value from 0.0 to 1.0.

This [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939841/how-do-i-fade-in-out-a-rectangle-or-text/1940958#1940958) provides code to show you how.